# Datepicker Format JS

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I have a datepicker which I want to change the format of. Currently dates are shown MM/DD/YYYY but I want the format to be DD-MM-YYY

```
<input id="single-date-picker" type="text"  class="form-control">
```

And the JS:

```
$("#single-date-picker").daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: !0,
    showDropdowns: !0
  }, function(e, t, a) {
    var n = moment().diff(e, "years");
    //alert("You are " + n + " years old.")
```

Any ideas as im new to JS

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me

```
$("#single-date-picker").daterangepicker({
  format:'DD-MM-YYYY',    
  singleDatePicker: true,
  showDropdowns: true
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can change the format by using `format` provided by the `Date Range Picker`.

```
$("#single-date-picker").daterangepicker({
  locale: {
     format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
  } 
});
```

[Here is the jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rLnycn80/10/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, however I'm looking at a single date not a range

Answer (score 0):

Do this : https://jsfiddle.net/faw405yf/1/

```
$("#single-date-picker").daterangepicker(
{
    locale: {
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
    },
    singleDatePicker: !0,
    showDropdowns: !0
}
```

---

If the above doesn't work, try this : https://jsfiddle.net/9uazkg3h/

```
$("#single-date-picker").daterangepicker({
    autoUpdateInput: false,
    singleDatePicker: !0,
    showDropdowns: !0
  },
  function(e, t, a) {
    var n = moment().diff(e, "years");
    alert("You are " + n + " years old.");
  }
);

$("#single-date-picker").on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
});
```

Comment: Nope still not changed??